# React: accessing the component that triggered a synthetic event

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a game using React. The game uses a `<Board />` component and several `<Piece />` components, which display `<img>` HTML elements. When the player clicks on a Piece, it is removed from the Board. Something like this:

```
<Board>
  <Piece />
  <Piece />
  <Piece />
</Board>
```

I have attached an `onClick` event listener to the Board. I can use `event.target` to get the `<img>` element that the player clicked on. It is very easy to use `event.target.classList.add("removed")` and to create a CSS rule that hides all elements with the "removed" class:

```
.removed {
  display: none;
}
```

However, this seems to violate the principles of React. I imagine that it would be better to modify the Board's `state` property, so that when it the Board component is rendered, none of the "removed" Pieces are shown.

This means that I need to obtain a pointer to the Piece component whose `<img>` element was clicked. I had expected to find such a pointer in the synthetic event that React generates, but no.

Currently, I maintain two arrays: one with the `state` data for each Piece component, and one containing a pointer to each `<img>` element. I find the index of the `<img>` element in the second array, and make changes to an object in the `state` array at the same index. But this feels like a hack.

Is there a more React-y way to approach this issue?

Comment: This is a very basic/common scenario, please try making a simple example https://codesandbox.io/, I'm sure you will get answered then. (Your current question missing additional information)

Comment: @DennisVash I've posted a new question with a JSFiddle example (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58061166/1927589), but I haven't found any other questions that refer to this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that this is not the *React way* of doing it. There is no need to "hide" the element as is usually done in vanilla JS or jQuery, React will handle that based on the `state` or props that contain information about which pieces are on the board.

You need to send an identifier to the piece in order to have a callback for the Parent component to update the state based on the pieces:

```
// constructor:

this.state = {
  pieces: ["pawn", "rook", "queen"]
};


// render:

{ this.state.pieces.map((piece, i) => (
  <Piece type={piece} onClick={() => this.deletePiece(i)} />
}
```

[Here's a codesandbox of a working example.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-jackson-wh6kz)

(**Note:** Ideally pieces would have an ID instead of just an index to avoid re-renders, but the important part of the example is to see how the variable `i` allows the callback to delete the piece back in the parent component)