# React with marching ants: a case for using ids?

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React. I am creating an app where the user can select a number of elements using a "marching ants" selection rectangle. When the mouse is released after the selection is made, the selected elements should disappear. The mouse might never interact directly with the elements that are selected and then removed.

I have all this working as you can see in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/gahj2x35/14/)

However, my technique relies on reading and writing the `id` and `class` properties of the HTML elements, and querying the DOM for information on which elements are selected. This happens specifically in the `_getSelectedSpanIds` method. It seems to me that this is contrary to the spirit of React, so I would appreciate any insights into how purify my approach.

For reference, the full code is shown below, but if the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/gahj2x35/14/) is still working, it would be much easier to explore the code there.

---

**index.html**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import "./style.css"


/**
 * this.props will be:
 * { data: nested list of strings to display
 * , drag: pointer to App.startDrag, for drawing marching ants rect
 * 
 * , selected: array of ids of spans selected by marching ants
 * , removed:  array of ids of spans removed after selection
 * }
 */
class Board extends React.Component {
  _getClassName(id) {
    let className = ""

    if (this.props.removed.indexOf(id) < 0) {
      if (this.props.selected.indexOf(id) < 0) {
        // This span is neither selected nor removed. Leave it alone
      } else {
        className = "selected"
      }

    } else {
      className = "removed"
    }

    return className
  }


  render () {
    const rows = this.props.data.map((rowData, rowIndex) => {
      const cells = rowData.map((cellData, cellIndex) => {
        const id = "cell-" + rowIndex + "-" + cellIndex
        const className = this._getClassName(id)

        return (
          <span       
            key={cellIndex}
            id={id}
            className={className}
          >
            {cellData}
          </span>
        )
      })

      return (
         <div
           key={rowIndex}
           className={"row-" + rowIndex}
          >
          {cells}
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div
        id="board"
        onMouseDown={this.props.drag}
      >
        {rows}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const Ants = ({ rect }) => {

  if (!rect) {
    console.log("No ants")
    return ""
  }

  const svg = (
    <svg
      width="100vw"
      height="100vh"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      style={{
        position: "fixed"
      , top: 0
      , left: 0
      , pointerEvents: "none"
      }}
    >
      <rect
        x={rect.x}
        y={rect.y}
        width={rect.width}
        height={rect.height}
        stroke="#000"
        strokeWidth="1"
        strokeOpacity="0.75"
        strokeDasharray="5,5"
        style={{ animation: "ants 1s linear infinite" }}
        fill="#000"
        fillOpacity="0.1"
      />
      <rect
        x={rect.x}
        y={rect.y}
        width={rect.width}
        height={rect.height}
        stroke="#fff"
        strokeWidth="1"
        strokeOpacity="0.75"
        strokeDasharray="5,5"
        style={{ animation: "tsan 1s linear infinite" }}
        fill="none"
      />
    </svg>
  )

  return svg
}



class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { rect: null, selected: [], removed: [] }
    this.startDrag = this.startDrag.bind(this)
  }


  startDrag(event) {
    const startX = event.pageX
    const startY = event.pageY

    const drag = event => {
      const x      = Math.min(startX, event.pageX)
      const right  = Math.max(startX, event.pageX)
      const width  = right - x
      const y      = Math.min(startY, event.pageY)
      const bottom = Math.max(startY, event.pageY)
      const height = bottom - y

      const rect = { x, y, right, bottom, width, height }
      const selected = this._getSelectedSpanIds(rect)

      this.setState({ rect, selected })
    }

    const stopDrag = () => {
      document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag, false)
      document.documentElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag, false)       

      const removed = this.state.removed.concat(this.state.selected)
      this.setState({ rect: null, selected: [], removed })
    }

    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false)
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag, false)
    drag(event) // treat case of a click with no mouse movement
  }


  _getSelectedSpanIds(rect) {
    const intersect = (rect1, rect2) => {
      return rect1.x < rect2.right
          && rect2.x < rect1.right
          && rect1.y < rect2.bottom
          && rect2.y < rect1.bottom
    }

    return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span:not(.removed)"))
                   .filter(span => (
                     intersect(span.getBoundingClientRect(), rect)
                   ))
                   .map(span => span.id)
  }


  render() {
    const data = [["⨷"], ["◯", ""], ["⚫", "", ""]]

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Board
          // Fixed
          data={data}
          drag={this.startDrag}
          // Variable
          selected={this.state.selected}
          removed={this.state.removed}
        />
        <Ants
          rect={this.state.rect}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**style.css**

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20vmin;
}

* {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

span.selected {
  background-color: #090;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

span.removed {
  opacity: 0.05;
}

div#board{
  background-color: #efe;
  height: 100vh;
}

div[class|="row"] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes ants {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 10; }
}

@keyframes tsan {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 5; }
}
```